# Get values in objects of custom class

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to store this result set (example):

```
Author_ID | Author_Name | CoAuthor_ID | Paper_ID | Venue_ID | Year  
------------------------------------------------------------------
677       | Nuno Vascon | 901706      | 812229   | 64309    | 2005
677       | Nuno Vascon | 901706      | 812486   | 65182    | 2005
677       | Nuno Vascon | 901706      | 818273   | 185787   | 2005  
1359      | Peng Shi    | 133112      | 812558   | 65182    | 2005
1359      | Peng Shi    | 266386      | 812558   | 65182    | 2005
1359      | Peng Shi    | 454557      | 812558   | 65182    | 2005  
...       | ...         | ...         | ...      | ...      | ...
```

in object of class. i.e. For a same `Year = 2005`, I have to store different `Author_ID`, `Author_Name`, `CoAuthor_ID`, `Paper_ID` and `Venue_ID` and these can be greater in number whereas showing just an example here.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT   AC.Author_ID, A.Author_Name, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AC.Paper_ID, AP.Venue_ID, AC.Year
FROM     AuthorCoAuthor AC
JOIN     AuthorPaper    AP ON AP.Author_ID = AC.Author_ID AND 
                              AP.Paper_ID  = AC.Paper_ID
JOIN     Author         A  ON A.Author_ID  = AC.Author_ID
WHERE    AC.Year = 2005
ORDER BY AC.Author_ID, AC.Year, AC.CoAuthor_ID, AC.Paper_ID, AP.Venue_ID
```

**Purpose**

To accommodate this method, I asked this question. The method is as:

```
public List<Author> CollectAuthors(int _year)
{
     List<Author> _eAthors = new List<Author>();
     // Get authors from database including all the information in rows for `Author_ID`  
    ...  
    return _eAuthors;  
}
```

How can I store this data in object of a class?

Comment: Perhaps by using [an ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)?

Comment: Create the db, and then let entity framework database-first generate the classes for you

Comment: What if he uses ADO?

Comment: @LuisLavieri EF generate classes that most of the code is unusable mean undesirable.

Comment: Is coauthor references to author? I mean is it FK to itself?

Comment: unusable? what do you mean @maliks ?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Let me add the query which populates this result for me (the shown result in question)

Comment: @LuisLavieri Mean I can't figure out those complex types of data properties, whether to use them or not

Comment: @maliks please, read this [Why use EF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsimmons/2008/05/17/why-use-the-entity-framework/)

Look up for some tutorial, and learn some `Linq`, you'll save yourself a long time in the long run

Comment: @LuisLavieri I need what I have commented at `Rene Vogt`'s answer, hope you have seen it. Now please tell do I need to use EF for that purpose ?

Comment: @LuisLavieri I have also shown the purpose (method) for which I need to ask the current question

Comment: @maliks, you can design the classes whatever you like them. Both posts are great answers. However, the fact is that they don't know how your db looks like in reality. They just have seen that joined table. So, if you are concerned that those classes are not going to make all the connections needed to your entities, let EF model the classes for you, and then you can make the joins and manipulate the data whatever you like using `linq`

Comment: @maliks that method is trivial once you have everything modeled as I mentioned before. You could do something like Rene posted on his answer

Comment: @LuisLavieri Right you suggested awesome towards Rene. Hope it'll help me

Comment: @maliks, I still think you are too confused. Please, do a simple tutorial of EF database-first and then everything will click.

Comment: @maliks. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739164/Entity-Framework-Tutorial-for-Beginners) is a good one for beginners

Comment: @LuisLavieri surely I'll go for it but I think that may be may be the Rene's suggestions would work!

Comment: Oh yeah. That will work for sure. But, there is probably more in your db than just this table.

Comment: @LuisLavieri I was creating classes myself at first, then I used EF but due to complexity I stepped back at self generating classes. But as you suggested I'll go once more for EF :)

Comment: Was it a wrong question, I'm amazed while seeing 2 down votes with it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two separate classes like this `Author`:

```
public class Author
{
     public int Author_ID { get; set; }
     public string Author_Name { get; set; }
     public int Year { get; set; }

     public List<AuthorData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and a class `AuthorData` like that:

```
public class AuthorData
{
    public int CoAuthor_ID { get; set; }
    public int Paper_ID { get; set; }
    public int Venue_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create instances like that:

```
List<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
// assuming you have a SqlCommand "command" executing the query you showed
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        int author_ID = reader.GetInt(0);
        Author author = authors.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Author_ID == author_ID);
        if (author == null)
        {
            author = new Author{
               Author_ID = author_ID,
               Author_Name = reader.GetString(1),
               Year = reader.GetInt(5),
               Data = new List<AuthorData>()
            };
            authors.Add(author);
        }

        author.Data.Add(new AuthorData{
             CoAuthor_ID = reader.GetInt(2),
             Paper_ID = reader.GetInt(3),
             Venue_ID = reader.GetInt(4)
        });
    }
}
```

This assumes that your ID's are `Int32` and not `Int64` and of course you should add error handling.

---

So let's say you have all your `Author`s in a `List<Author>`. Then you can select all the `Authors` for a specific year like this:

```
public List<Author> AuthorsOfYear(List<Author> fullList, int year)
{
    return fullList.Where(author => author.Year == year).ToList();
}
```

and for a year range:

```
public List<Author> AuthorsOfYear(List<Author> fullList, int startyear, int endyear)
{
    return fullList.Where(author => 
          author.Year >= startyear && author.Year <= endyear).ToList();
}
```

Comment: @Rene--Can I use same query in C# editor in `CollectAuthors` method for data reading from database or some other I may need to alter it?

Comment: @maliks Edited my answer to show an example how to get the list of authors via `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: @maliks but I mixed something: in your query you already filter for a specific year, so the methods for that are obsolete. I assumed your SqlDataReader fetches all rows.

Comment: @Rene--Right, but what if I give year ranges i.e. startyear and endyear

Comment: @Rene--You may add the code lines in comment for year range data reading please

Comment: @maliks in your query? well then you get the corresponding records. don't understand your question.

Comment: @Rene--then in my query the only change will be i.e. `AC.Year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2006` or something like this

Comment: @Rene--Hope you add lines for year range data reading in `List<Author> authors;` Thanks :) Rene

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. The method is there in my answer. Or do you mean the SQL syntax for your query? You already showed that in your own comment. There is no need for any further code changes, as the SQL then returns only the records you want. I'm about to leave now, so I guess you have to solve this on your own.

Comment: @Rene--you mean I have to execute query just once and get all the records in `authors` that is the object of class `Authors` ? and then get authors by using your suggested two methods ? Is it so ?

Comment: @maliks yes that's a possibility though I can't tell if this is the optimal solution for you.

Comment: @Rene--its mean I haven't to pass Year as a parameter to CollectAuthors method and also there is no need to use`WHERE` clause in SQL query right

Comment: @Rene--As you suggested in your answer here, I just want to made a modification here that...in `AuthorData` class the property i.e. `int Paper_ID` is to be defined as: `public Dictionary<Int32, Int32> _Paper;` then how will we read it using `SQLReader`?

Comment: @Rene---will you suggest this?